# How to draw a plane inside a cube?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, cube, plane

I am wondering about how to draw a 2D plane inside the 3D cube. The task, is that the 2D plane should separate the cube into two parts (should be the parts equal or not? doesn't matter)

Here is the code for drawing a cube in 3D.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')

#draw cube
r = [-1, 1]
for s, e in combinations(np.array(list(product(r,r,r))), 2):
    if np.sum(np.abs(s-e)) == r[1]-r[0]:
        ax.plot3D(*zip(s,e), color="#000000");
```

[image: Image of cube in 3D]